# How to parse the response from git log ? I need to get the commit hash and the commit message

Tags: php, git, parsing, preg-match-all

I am executing a command "git log" from php using shell_exec() function and getting the following response. How can i parse the response and get the commit hash and commit message ?

```
commit baedfa411c58584c4a98f3a632b7f3231500f92c
Author: XYZ
Date:   Tue Apr 12 23:04:33 2016 +0530

commiting 3rd commit

commit 251654c5f6f256fe6e23c2c85f1a70594aae00d4
Author: XYZ
Date:   Tue Apr 12 22:37:21 2016 +0530

commiting 2nd commit

commit 3be3198a20d902e24e6b187cd0666ed0d5ee6c4d
Author: XYZ
Date:   Tue Apr 12 22:34:31 2016 +0530

initial commit
```

Comment: Do not parse anything from the output of `git log`, as it may change in future Git releases. Rely on lower-level Git commands such as `git rev-list` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the next:

```
git log --oneline --format="%H %s"
```

If you need to use this output in php you can add some key between values and use `explode()` in each line to get the values. For example:

```
git log --oneline --format=%H:::%s
```

Where `:::` is de delimiter, the use it in php explode.

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 2):

use `git log --oneline` instead of `git log`